# What does "they took the car out for a run" mean?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What does "they took the car out for a run" mean?

Is it a phrasal verb?

Comment: For a run=for a drive.

Comment: *[run](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/run_2): a short journey that you do in a car for pleasure* [MM]

Answer (score 2):

The verb is "took", past tense of "take".  It's not a phrasal verb.  "A run" is a noun meaning (in this context) "a short journey by car"

It suggests that the purpose was not to get to a destination but to enjoy the drive.

It is related to the verb "to run" meaning "to operate (machinery)"

Comment: can I use it for other vehicles like a bike, motorbike or an airplane?

Comment: I think "ride" would be more normal with bikes, and planes are too costly for it to come up much in my conversation.  Probably not for planes.

Comment: "Out for a run" is used for small, private planes. "Test run" can be used for commercial planes, for a trip where the object is not to go somewhere, but to test the plane.